# Help with Folder permission problem with Oracle DB 7 and Solaris 7

Tags: solaris, oracle

I was wondering if anyone else has come across this issue with Solaris 7 and Oracle Database 7, I set the permissions of the folder as such chown -R oracle:dba /opt/oracle
but when trying to install the database I keep getting permission denied even no I set it and I checked and it all had read/write/execute but soon as I goto installer and get to ocommon section it resets the permissions back so that the gorup dba no longer has write permission, anyone got any ideas ?

Thanks, yours Simon

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal in CDE, exec

```
chown -R oracle:dba /opt/oracle
```

and then

```
chmod -R 775 /opt/oracle
```

and then start the Oracle Universal Installer (from terminal, you need graphic environment only to use the Installer)

Comment: I did that but it still says it don't have permission even if console installer

Comment: @Wpgn, I edited my answer, please try this way.

Comment: I did that and its still same out come I don't no what's going on with it, it makes dba writeable but soon as I load up database installer it resets to un-writable and gives error

screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/2M42bVr/lo.jpg

Comment: @Wpgn, as with user you run the installer? You should use oracle user. And IMHO this is not supported configuration (Oracle database 7 on Solaris 7)

Comment: here screen shot of how I load it, I did your commands first so on to make sure
https://i.ibb.co/vz9cmZs/lo.jpg

funny thing is it can write some of the folders but not the ocommon so on dont understand it at all.

Comment: @Wpgn, when you switch to `oracle` user use command `su - oracle`. Otherwise you will not get the target user environments

Comment: @Wpgn, and the permission I propose is `775`,not `755`

Comment: ooo I forgot to change to 775 thats it thanks Romeo :)